# Linux Selenium Chromedriver can't connect to chrome version

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm transferring my python scraper to a vps on Ubuntu. I've installed chromedriver using apt get and I'm getting an error when running my script.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:51757
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 108
Current browser version is 107.0.5304.121
```

Does anyone know how in bash to fix this? Do I change the chrome version, because I'm not sure how to do that, and I don't know where it is found on my filesystem.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add how you've downloaded the chromedriver using apt-get? I think you need to modify that.

Comment: Instead of downloading chromedriver for each updated version of chrome browser, use WebDriverManager.

Answer (score 0):

You have to  have the version that your Selenium driver was downloaded for.

If you want to maintain your 107.0.5304.121 version on Chrome, download the selenium 107.x.x.x driver

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

You can check here all the latest versions